# Test if user logged in PC in the network

Tags: active-directory, monitoring, powershell

How can I check if a specific user is logged in on a specific computer on my active directory network? I am administrator in this network and would prefer to do it with powershell but I am open to other options.

Comment: Do you want to test for a specific user, a specific computer, a specific user on a specific computer or just anyone on any computer?

Comment: Specific user in a specific computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PSLoggedOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545) from the fine folks at SysInternals will do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little function I whipped up to do this natively in powershell, without requiring PSLoggedOn.

It's very rough and could certainly use some polish, but it demonstrates the important information: use Get-WmiObject and query the Wim32_ComputerSystem class for the username property.

Unfortunately I think this is only accurate for locally logged on users -- you won't be able to see if a person is logged in over RDP with this method.

Here's the code:

```
function Test-LoggedOn {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string]$username,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$computername
    )
    [regex]$pattern = "({\w}\\)?$($username.replace('\','\\'))"
    $wmi = Get-WmiObject -query "select username from win32_computersystem" -ComputerName $computername
    return $wmi.username -match $pattern
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a powershell function based on this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/17/use-powershell-to-detect-if-a-workstation-is-in-use.aspx). It shows some text of the psloggedon command that I still don't know how to remove and the function has a loot of room for improvement... But it works, so HTH somebody else.

```
function UserLoggedOn{
    param($pc, $user)

    # creates an object with the fields Computer, Domain and User.  
    [object[]]$sessions = Invoke-Expression "d:\scripts\PsLoggedon.exe -x -l \\$pc" |
    Where-Object {$_ -match '^\s{2,}((?<domain>\w+)\\(?<user>\S+))|(?<user>\S+)'} |
    Select-Object @{ Name="Computer"
    Expression={"AGEXLUXS20"} 
    }, 
    @{ 
        Name='Domain' 
        Expression={$matches.Domain} 
    }, 
    @{ 
        Name='User' 
        Expression={$Matches.User} 
    }   

    $userfound = $false
    foreach($session in $sessions) {
        if ($session.User -eq $user) { $userfound = $true }
    }       

    if ($userfound) { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$user is logged on \\$pc." }
    else  { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$user is NOT logged on \\$pc." }

}
```